# ListLinePlot of sum giving zeroes at nonzero values

Tags: plotting, wolfram-cloud

I was using Wolfram|Alpha to graph the sums of
$$\sum^k_{n=0}\frac{\sin(2^n)}{n}.$$
After querying `sum n=1 to infinity of sin(2^n)/n` and clicking `More Terms` several times, I got [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%3D1+to+infinity+of+sin(2%5En)%2Fn):

[image: Plot from 1 to 641]

Eager to get more terms without having to click a button so many times, clicked Open Code, which gave me `ListLinePlot[Accumulate[Table[Sin[2^n]/n, {n, 1, 641}]]]`. However, the plot I got looked like this instead:

[image: Plot from 1 to ~540 then lots of 0s]

Is this caused by not having a plan for the Wolfram Language, or something else I'm not aware of? I also tried `ListLinePlot[Table[Sum[Sin[2^i]/i,{i,1,n}], {n, 1, 641}]]` which gave similar results.

I also tried using the free release of wolframscript but was unable to get a picture, the command line returned `-Graphics-` and I couldn't find how to output an image online.

Is there a way apart from Wolfram|Alpha to render these images?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `N`

```
 ListLinePlot[Table[N@Sum[Sin[2^i]/i, {i, 1, n}], {n, 1, 641}], 
     AspectRatio -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot[Table[N@Sum[Sin[2^i]/i, {i, 1, n}], {n, 1, 641}], 
  AspectRatio -> Full] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot[
  Table[N@Sum[Sin[2^i]/i, {i, 1, n}], {n, 1, 1001}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I've just tried doing this with 1001 instead of 641 but it's taking a long time to load... is this because the image is large? Can I remove the AspectRatio thing?

Comment: In my environment,`AspectRatio` doesn't affect on the time.(its around 3.1 seconds).  anyway,you can remove `AspectRatio`,of course.

Comment: by the way,If it is heavy in your environment, please use this.　http://cpp.sh/3mb7s